# What is the best way to import an XML string into a SQL Server table

Tags: java, xml

I am working with a 3rd product called JPOS and it has an XMLPackager whereby I get a string from this packager that contains a record in an XML format such as:

```
<MACHINE><B000>STRING_VALUE</B000><B002>STRING_VALUE</B002><B003>STRING_VALUE</B003><B004>STRING_VALUE</B004><B007>STRING_VALUE</B007><B011>STRING_VALUE</B011><B012>STRING_VALUE</B012><B013>STRING_VALUE</B013><B015>STRING_VALUE</B015><B018>STRING_VALUE</B018><B028>STRING_VALUE</B028><B032>STRING_VALUE</B032><B035>STRING_VALUE</B035><B037>STRING_VALUE</B037><B039>STRING_VALUE</B039><B041>STRING_VALUE</B041><B043>STRING_VALUE</B043><B048>STRING_VALUE</B048><B049>STRING_VALUE</B049><B058>STRING_VALUE</B058><B061>STRING_VALUE</B061><B063>STRING_VALUE</B063><B127>STRING_VALUE</B127></MACHINE>
```

I have a SQL server table that contains a column for each of the  listed. Not that it matters but I could potentially have  thru  defined with specific STRING_VALUEs.  I'm not sure what is the best way to go about this in Java.  My understanding is that SQL Server can take an XML string (not document) and do an insert.  Is it best to parse each value and then put into a list that populate each value into?  This is the first time I've used an XML file and therefore trying to get some help/direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, one of my colleagues was able to help and provide a quick answer.  I'll try it from my Java code and it looks like it should work great.  Thanks anyway.

Here is the SP that she created whereby I can pass in my XML string and bit value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sbssp_InsertArchivedMessages]
```

(
      @doc varchar(max),
      @fromTo bit
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @idoc int, @lastId int
      EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc

```
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages]
  SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/MACHINE', 2) WITH [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages]

  SET @lastId = (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tblArchivedMessages'))

  UPDATE [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages] 
    SET FromToMach = @fromTo 
    WHERE ID = @lastId
```

END
GO

Regards.